# Referring back to selected value in WHERE clause

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following sql that will display test score values:

```
SELECT  s.dcid, s.lastfirst, s.student_number, s.grade_level, s.schoolid,

(SELECT stc.numscore
   FROM studenttestscore stc
   JOIN testscore ts ON stc.testscoreid = ts.id
   JOIN test t on ts.testid = t.id
   JOIN studenttest st ON stc.studenttestid = st.id
   WHERE stc.studentid = s.id
   AND t.id = 451
   AND ts.id = 857
   AND st.termid LIKE '24%'
   AND ROWNUM = 1) as FALL,

(SELECT stc.numscore
   FROM studenttestscore stc
   JOIN testscore ts ON stc.testscoreid = ts.id
   JOIN test t on ts.testid = t.id
   JOIN studenttest st ON stc.studenttestid = st.id
   WHERE stc.studentid = s.id
   AND t.id = 501
   AND ts.id = 1001
   AND st.termid LIKE '24%'
   AND ROWNUM = 1) as WINTER,

(SELECT stc.numscore
   FROM studenttestscore stc
   JOIN testscore ts ON stc.testscoreid = ts.id
   JOIN test t on ts.testid = t.id
   JOIN studenttest st ON stc.studenttestid = st.id
   WHERE stc.studentid = s.id
   AND t.id = 551
   AND ts.id = 1051
   AND st.termid LIKE '24%'
   AND ROWNUM = 1) as SPRING

FROM students s

WHERE s.grade_level = 1 

ORDER BY s.lastfirst
```

As written, this returns all students and what their scores were during the Fall, Winter, and Spring testing sessions.  What I need to do now is limit the list of students to only those where their scores are below a specific benchmark during the Fall and Winter.  I know I can accomplish this by adding to the WHERE clause with something like:

```
WHERE s.grade_level = 1
AND (SELECT stc.numscore
   FROM studenttestscore stc
   JOIN testscore ts ON stc.testscoreid = ts.id
   JOIN test t on ts.testid = t.id
   JOIN studenttest st ON stc.studenttestid = st.id
   WHERE stc.studentid = s.id
   AND t.id = 451
   AND ts.id = 857
   AND st.termid LIKE '24%'
   AND ROWNUM = 1) < 28

AND (SELECT stc.numscore
   FROM studenttestscore stc
   JOIN testscore ts ON stc.testscoreid = ts.id
   JOIN test t on ts.testid = t.id
   JOIN studenttest st ON stc.studenttestid = st.id
   WHERE stc.studentid = s.id
   AND t.id = 501
   AND ts.id = 1001
   AND st.termid LIKE '24%'
   AND ROWNUM = 1) < 37
```

My question though is, is this the most efficient way of creating the selection criteria?  Is there a way I can refer back to the selected score's alias names, FALL, and WINTER?  It does not work when I test it with

```
WHERE s.grade_level = 1
AND FALL < 28
AND WINTER < 37
```

Comment: In most RDBMS (including Oracle) you **cannot** use column `aliases` in `WHERE` clause.  You can wrap your query in another one and then use these aliases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply nest your Select in a Derived Table (aka Inline View) and then you can use the aliased columns in WHERE:

```
SELECT *
FROM 
 (
   SELECT  s.dcid, s.lastfirst, s.student_number, s.grade_level, s.schoolid,

    (SELECT stc.numscore
       FROM studenttestscore stc
       JOIN testscore ts ON stc.testscoreid = ts.id
       JOIN test t ON ts.testid = t.id
       JOIN studenttest st ON stc.studenttestid = st.id
       WHERE stc.studentid = s.id
       AND t.id = 451
       AND ts.id = 857
       AND st.termid LIKE '24%'
       AND ROWNUM = 1) AS FALL,

    (SELECT stc.numscore
       FROM studenttestscore stc
       JOIN testscore ts ON stc.testscoreid = ts.id
       JOIN test t ON ts.testid = t.id
       JOIN studenttest st ON stc.studenttestid = st.id
       WHERE stc.studentid = s.id
       AND t.id = 501
       AND ts.id = 1001
       AND st.termid LIKE '24%'
       AND ROWNUM = 1) AS WINTER,

    (SELECT stc.numscore
       FROM studenttestscore stc
       JOIN testscore ts ON stc.testscoreid = ts.id
       JOIN test t ON ts.testid = t.id
       JOIN studenttest st ON stc.studenttestid = st.id
       WHERE stc.studentid = s.id
       AND t.id = 551
       AND ts.id = 1051
       AND st.termid LIKE '24%'
       AND ROWNUM = 1) AS SPRING

    FROM students s

    WHERE s.grade_level = 1
 ) dt
WHERE FALL < 28
AND WINTER < 37
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Common Table Expressions, you can reference fields from the CTE select statements in the where clause of the main query.  They also clean up the structure a little and the reuse limits the number of times you need to copy+paste common predicates (e.g. - AND st.termid LIKE '24%')

```
WITH TermTestData AS (
    SELECT  ts.testid
        ,   ts.id
        ,   stc.numscore
        ,   stc.studentid
    FROM    studenttestscore AS stc
    JOIN    testscore AS ts
        ON  ts.id = stc.testscoreid
    JOIN    studenttest AS st
        ON  st.id = stc.testscoreid
    WHERE   st.termid LIKE '24%'
), SemesterScores AS (
    SELECT  s.dcid, s.lastfirst, s.student_number, s.grade_level, s.schoolid
        ,   (SELECT td.numscore
             FROM   TermTestData AS td
             WHERE  td.studentid = s.id
             AND td.id = 451
             AND td.id = 857
             AND ROWNUM = 1) as FALL
        ,   (SELECT td.numscore
             FROM   TermTestData AS td
             WHERE  td.studentid = s.id
             AND td.id = 501
             AND td.id = 1001
             AND ROWNUM = 1) as WINTER
        ,   (SELECT td.numscore
             FROM   TermTestData AS td
             WHERE  td.studentid = s.id
             AND td.id = 551
             AND td.id = 1051
             AND ROWNUM = 1) as SPRING
    FROM    students AS s
)
SELECT  *
FROM    SemesterScores
WHERE   FALL < 28
AND     WINTER < 37
```

Side Note: If you are using Oracle 11g, you can pivot the data to avoid the having select statements for single-value fields

Answer (score -1):

If this is MYSQL you could try making it like:

```
WHERE s.grade_level = 1
HAVING FALL < 28 AND WINTER < 37
```

I believe "HAVING" makes another pass and would pick up the alias.